# Select first n of 1 values from a binary vector (0,1) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a binary vector, *e.g*:

```
x = [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
```

I want to keep the first 4 elements that are '1' (substituting the rest with '0's). In my example the resulting vector should be:

```
z = [ 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First construct a vector of zeroes, then use `find`:

```
z = false(size(x));
z(find(x, 4)) = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for `find` for a binary vector. Use `cumsum` instead!

```
>> z = x;
>> z(cumsum( z, 2 ) > 4) = 0;
```

This solution (unlike `find`-based answers) can process a stack of such binary vectors **at once** (all you need is to verify that `cumsum` works on the proper dimension).

Comment: It's still `O(n)`, but less efficient and less intuitive :)

Comment: Now you're just overcomplicating the question :)

Comment: Mind you, your solution won't work for matrices as well (you messed up the indexing a bit). I've taken the liberty of fixing it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
z=x;
A=find(z);
z(A(5:end))=0;
```

Idea here is to make all, but first n, 1's to 0's

Comment: double subscripting doesn't work in MATLAB. You'll need an intermediate variable for that.

Comment: @EitanT I don't have Matlab right now. But tested using `Octave` and it worked fine. Not sure if it's compatible.

Comment: @jkshah when it comes to double scripting - matlab and octave are **not** compatible

Comment: @Shai Thanks for pointing that out. Since I am Linux user, I generally use Octave. won't even `(find(z))(5:end)` work ??

Comment: @jkshah Matlab works fine on Linux as well. But I'm afraid no double scripting... at all... :(....

Comment: @Shai Updated my ans. I know but license issue in ofc laptop, I'm afraid!

Comment: @jkshah ah... the price of Matlab... They are a greedy bunch, are they?

Comment: @Shai Not sure. I used to work on MatLab in college, Now a days just solving these questions for fun with easily available resources. Nothing much.